# error while using jsonEncode in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, json

```
class Calculator implements CalculatorInterface
{

     public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager

)
{

    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;

}

$age=array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");

$jsonHelper = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Sitemap\Helper\Data');

        $jsonHelper->jsonEncode($age);
}
```

Error is :

> Fatal Error: 'Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Sitemap\Helper\Data::jsonEncode()'

Comment: How about your current issue? Solved?

Answer (score 0):

the error is jsonEncode method located at get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')